# How to clear a text-field on focus with AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

The theme question sais it all.

I have an input text-field on the stage that has some text describing text in it before the user types anything. Now, how do I clear this text when the user focuses on (clicks) the field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Listen for the `FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN` event on your textfield and clear it once that fires.
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/FocusEvent.html

Answer (score 3):

Try this Code

```
  txtMessage.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, clearBox);
  function textclearBox(FocusEvent)
   {
    txtUser.text="";//To Clear the Text Box
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it. (Although, my AS3 is a bit rusty.)

```
textbox.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, clearBox);

function clearBox(e:FocusEvent){
  textbox.setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

important: userName is MovieClip and this movieClip's inside ı have TextField which name is txt.

```
userName.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_IN, clearBox);
function clearBox(evt:FocusEvent):void
{
    userName.text="";
}
```